The Dot Product of Position Vector $\vec{r}(t)$ and Velocity Vector $\frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt}$



As excerpted above, Wolfram Mathworld states this:

If $\vec{r}(t)$ is the position vector, then
$$ \vec{r}(t) \cdot  \frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt} = |\vec{r}(t)| \left| \frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt} \right|.$$

I understand and agree with how they arrived the derivation, but I am confused because the following example contradicts its conclusion.  What am I missing?
Example
If $\vec{r}(t) = \cos(t)\hat{i} + \sin(t)\hat{j}$, then $\frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt} = -\sin(t)\hat{i} + \cos(t)\hat{j}$.
Observe that
$$|\vec{r}(t)| = \sqrt{\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t)} = 1$$
and
$$|\frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt}| = \sqrt{(-\sin(t))^2 + (\cos(t))^2} = 1.$$
So,
$$ |\vec{r}(t)|\left|\frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt}\right| = 1. $$
However,
\begin{align*}
\vec{r}(t) \cdot \frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt} &= (\cos(t)\hat{i} + \sin(t)\hat{j}) \cdot (-\sin(t)\hat{i} + \cos(t)\hat{j}) \\
&= -\sin(t)\cos(t) + \sin(t)\cos(t) \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
In conclusion,
$$\vec{r}(t) \cdot \frac{\vec{r}(t)}{dt} = 0 \ne 1 = |\vec{r}(t)|\left|\frac{\vec{r}(t)}{dt}\right|. $$

$v=\frac{dr}{dt}$ can be positive or negative so $v$ cannot be the magnitude of the velocity as stated

Obviously, this is about the derivative of a vector where we shall evaluate the change in its magnitude plus the change in its direction.

Your example is correct, but I believe your understanding of Wolfram Mathworld's equation is wrong. Because $\vec a\cdot\vec b=|\vec a||\vec b|\cos\theta$, your listed equation only holds when $\theta=0$, which clearly doesn't always apply!
The main misunderstanding comes from the term $\frac{dr}{dt}$, which you interpret as $\left|\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\right|$. Looking at Wolfram's derivation, $r$ refers to the magnitude of $\vec r$, so $\frac{dr}{dt}$ is the change in the magnitude of the position vector, not the magnitude of the change.
So in your example, $r=\sqrt{\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)}=1$, so $\frac{dr}{dt}=0$, satisfying the equality .

What WA is really saying is..
$$⃗ ()⋅ \frac{⃗ ()}{}=|⃗ ()| \frac{|⃗ ()|}{}$$
The conclusion should be that
$$⃗ ()⋅ \frac{⃗ ()}{}=rv_r$$
where $v_r$ is the radial component of the velocity





$$ \vec{r}(t) \cdot  \frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt} = |\vec{r}(t)| \left| \frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt} \right|.$$

The error is in Wolfram's final equality, which you have correctly transcribed/translated.
Correction:
\begin{align}\vec{r}(t) \cdot  \frac{\mathrm d\vec{r}(t)}{\mathrm dt} &= |\vec{r}(t)|  \frac{\mathrm d\left|\vec{r}(t)\right|}{\mathrm dt} \\&\ne rv\\&= |\vec{r}(t)| \left| \frac{\mathrm d\vec{r}(t)}{\mathrm dt} \right|.\end{align}

Wolfram Mathworld is actually incorrect, not in its derivation, but in stating speed $\displaystyle v\ (= |{{\bf v}|}) = \frac{dr}{dt}\ = (\frac{d|{{\bf r}|}}{dt})$.
That is not the usual meaning of speed. The usual meaning of speed (which is indeed the magnitude of velocity as correctly stated by Mathworld) should be given by $\displaystyle v\ (= \left|{\bf v}\right|) = \left|\frac{d\bf r}{dt}\right|)$.
Note carefully exactly where the magnitude is being taken. In general, $|\frac{d\bf r}{dt}| \neq \frac{d|\bf r|}{dt}$, and only the former is speed. The speed can be viewed as a scalar quantity measured along the path of travel of a particle, and is also equal to the magnitude of the velocity vector.
As a simple illustration of how Wolfram Mathworld's statement leads to nonsensical conclusions, consider the simple case of $2$-d planar circular motion at a constant radius of orbit from the origin and a fixed angular speed $\omega$.
If we do it correctly, speed $\displaystyle v = \left|\frac{d\bf r}{dt}\right| = \left|\frac{{\bf i} dx + {\bf j} dy}{dt}\right| = \left|\frac{{\bf i} (-r\sin\theta) d\theta + {\bf j} r\cos\theta d\theta}{dt}\right| = r\omega$, as we expect.
But if we did it according to Mathworld's definition, speed $\displaystyle v = \frac{d|\bf r|}{dt} = 0$, which is clearly not what's expected. That's basically radial speed, and does not take the tangential component into account.
